# why does the for loop run twice only

Tags: java

**i do not understand why the for loop runs twice, the first value to be printed should be 2 and the last value should be 16 and not 4 since 4 is still less than 10**

i have done a for loop that increments the initial value by one but i have not tried to increment the initial value by multiplying it by the first value

```
for (int i = 2; i <10; i = i*i) {

   System.out.println(i);

}
```

i expected it to run 4 times but it ran just two times

Comment: When `i` is 16, it won't enter the loop body because 16 isn't less than 10.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For these cases you should learn to debug your code for better self understanding

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. Is is basic calculus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop is equivalent to this:

```
int i = 2;      // Initializer
while (i < 10)  // Condition
{
    System.out.println(i);
    i = i * i;  // Update part
}
```

Note how it will never enter the *body* of the loop when `i` is 10 or greater - so it will never print 16.

In other words, the execution looks like this:

- Set `i` to 2.
- Check: is `i` less than 10? Yes, so enter the body of the loop.
- Print `i`.
- Set `i = i * i`, so it's now 4.
- Check: is `i` less than 10? Yes, so enter the body of the loop.
- Print `i`.
- Set `i = i * i`, so it's now 16.
- Check: is `i` less than 10? No, so finish.

Answer (score 5):

Finding what your code is doing is easy with a paper sheet and a pen...

```
first run, i = 2 -> i < 10 == true -> print 2
second run, i = 2*2 = 4 -> i < 10 == true -> print 4
third run, i = 4*4 = 16 -> i < 10 == false -> out
```

Answer (score 2):

I try to explain how works for.

```
1) You initialized variable i = 2
2) Check i < 10
3) Print(i) = 2
```

--- NEXT ----

```
1) i = i*i (2*2) = 4
2) Check i < 10 = 4<10 = true
3) Print(i) = 4
```

--- NEXT ----

```
1) i = i*i (4*4) = 16
2) Check i < 10 = 16<10 = false
3) EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

First time `i = 2`, loop ran
second time `i = 4`, loop ran
third time `i = 16`, loop failed => break

Welcome to stackoverflow. For these cases you should learn to debug your code for better self understanding

Answer (score 1):

You are squaring. 2,4,16 but 16 is greater than i<10 so it does not do that

Answer (score 1):

Because of `i = i*i`

```
i = 2

1. i = 2*2 = 4 (4 < 10)
2. i = 4 * 2 = 8 (8 < 10)
3. i = 8 * 2 = 16 (16 > 10)
```